# How to test docker-compose with different config files?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have a **docker-compose.local.yml** file that looks like this:

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: "rabbitmq:latest"
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    volumes:
      - "./enabled_plugins:/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins"
  abc-service: &a-service
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}unicorn/a-service:${DOCKER_IMAGE_LABEL:-latest}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./debugging/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - GOOGLE_SHEET_TAB=abc
    configs:
      - source: abc-service
        target: ./bin/csv/main.csv
  def-service:
    <<: *a-service
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - GOOGLE_SHEET_TAB=def
    configs:
      - source: def-service
        target: ./bin/csv/main.csv
configs:
  abc-service:
    file: ./csvs/abc.csv
  def-service:
    file: ./csvs/def.csv
```

So this creates 3 services... a RabbitMQ service, a service called *abc-service* and a service called *def-service* that copies from abc-service but changes the environment variable of google sheet tab.

Both these services run off of different csv files.

I have a folder structure like

```
-
  - src
  - bin
     - csv
  - csvs
```

my Dockerfile copies **src** and **bin** to my container.  I want my docker-compose to copy the correct csv in the **csvs** folder for that service to the **bin/csv** folder as specified in the config section.

When I try and run my services locally, they don't have the csv copied to the folder.  This seems to be because it requires docker swarm to be running.

Am I doing this correctly?  I've seen a lot of talk about having to run CLI commands to add the CSV files as docker config variables... But i don't fully understand this and how it will later work with my gitlab auto deployment?  Also how can i easily test my application is using the correct (or at least copying the right) csv to the **bin/csv** folder?

Comment: You should check out this GitHub repo - https://github.com/docker/app which helps you to parametrize your configuration in docker-compose file.